# Django looks for template under djstripe/templates/djstripe/ instead of djstripe/templates/ (TemplateDoesNotExist)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm working on a Django 1.9.7 project using the dj-stripe library. I'm using the latest commit on the [`#162-api-updates-through_2015-07-28`](https://github.com/kavdev/dj-stripe/tree/%23162-api-updates-through_2015-07-28) branch of the dj-stripe repository, which is `1f0ed7c1`.

When trying to load a template `accounts.html` (at `/Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/djstripe/account.html`), I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception. This `accounts.html` template extends another template, `djstripe/base.html`, located at `/Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/base.html`.

Django tries to look for this `base.html` template at the incorrect path `/Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/djstripe/base.html`.

I tried changing the `{% extends "djstripe/base.html" %}` to `{% extends "base.html" %}` in the `accounts.html` file, but that didn't help.

So Django looks under `djstripe/templates/djstripe/` rather than just under `djstripe/templates/`, resulting in this error.

The message on the debug error page was:

#### Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
```

...

This is my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djstripe'
]
```

This is my `TEMPLATES` setting

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('djstripe.urls', namespace='djstripe')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings file, when 'DIRS' is left empty, Django will look for templates only in app_name/templates directory, because you have set 'APP_DIRS': True, by default.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'DIRS': [],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In your case, Django is looking for templates in:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
```

but there is no base.html in djstripe/templates.
You can move your template files in:

```
/Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/
```

or you can add path to your templates in DIRS.
here is explanation:
[Django DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Setting my `DIRS` setting to `'DIRS': ['/Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/'],` results in one extra line in the template loader postmortem: `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)`. I know that the file at this path exists though (and it is the correct one), but I'm not sure why Django doesn't see this. I'd rather not move or alter the template files unless I have to as they are third party.

Comment: You are adding the same path, which is using Django by default.
Add: '/Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/djstripe/'

Comment: You're right, that is the correct path, but setting that results in a new error in the template loader postmortem: `django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/james/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/djstripe/templates/djstripe/base.html (Skipped)`. I will have to work out why it is skipping loading the correct template.